# git: exchange the order of two commits before (including) common ancestor of multiple branches

Tags: git

Suppose I have the following branch structure on GIT:

```
A --- B --- C --- D --- E
            +---- F --- G
            +---- H --- I
```

Three branches, with common base `C`.

What I want to do is to exchange the order of B and C, to produce the following structure:

```
A --- C --- B --- D --- E
            +---- F --- G
            +---- H --- I
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with an interactive rebase.

```
git checkout <branch-E>
git rebase -i <sha1-A>
```

Reorder B and C.  This gives us the following history:

```
A --- C'--- B'--- D'--- E'
  \
   -- B --- C --- F --- G
              \
               -- H --- I
```

However, we don't want to repeat this for the other two branches.  If we do, we would create new commits for B and C, because the commit timestamps would be different.  We want to reuse the same commits.

We can fix it in the other two branches using a simpler rebase command:

```
git rebase --onto <sha1-B'> <sha1-C> <branch-G>
git rebase --onto <sha1-B'> <sha1-C> <branch-I>
```

This gives us the following history:

```
               -- D'--- E'
              /
A --- C'--- B'--- F'--- G'
              \
               -- H'--- I'
```